# Finding annotated counterpart after BLASTn with efetch (Biopython)

Tags: python, sequence-annotation, blastn, entrez, efetch

I am creating a pipeline for the identification of unknown transcripts. After a local BLASTn search of the transcripts, I have a large list of the respective hits with different genomes. I have the accession code of the respective genome, start/end coordinates, and the strand where the hit is found. Now, I would like to find if the genome where the hit was found is annotated within the coordinates returned by BLAST.

I have found the possibility of using efetch to search for each genome via Biopython, but this only returns the whole annotation, even though I limit the search to the specific coordinates with:

```
Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", id="CP054847.1", strand="2", seq_start="326053", seq_end="326786", retmode="xml")
```

Of course, I could parse the XML and look for possible annotations within the given range, but not only would this be quite computationally intense since I expect around 10.000+ hits to be searched, but it also seems to return the same results for the plus/minus strand, even though the annotations should be strand-specific.

I have also intended to use the standalone tool of efetch, but it would be easier to integrate the search to the pipeline using Biopython.

Do you have any ideas why `Entrez.efetch` is returning the whole `xml` or is there any fast way of filtering the output? Do you have maybe another alternative/idea for this step? I would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: can you find any difference between https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/CP054847.1/ and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_CP054847.1 database entries ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `seq_start` and `seq_end` are sensitive to the direction. Try swapping the two.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you can get the `blastn` output in a `BED` format:

```
genomeA_contig001    hit_start    hit_end    query_transcript    score   strand
genomeB_contig021    hit_start    hit_end    query_transcript    score   strand
```

which will contain all the unknown hits to all genomes.

All you need is a set of `GTF` files specific for `genomeA`, `genomeB` and so on where you add the suitable prefix (`genomeA_` for `GTF` describing genes/exons in that genome and so on). For transcript hits you may start with just the annotated exons. Next run:

`bedtools intersect -wao -a all.transctipts.hits.bed -b all_annotated_exons.gtf my_result.tsv`

to get all the overlaps with number of overlapping bases.
Filter and sort the `my_result.tsv` possibly importing it into a data frame using `pandas` or `polars`.